# Beamer: File ended while scanning use of \frame

Tags: beamer

I keep getting the error "File ended while scanning use of `\frame`".  Every other question I've read says they are missing an `\end{frame}` somewhere.  I've looked at my code forward and backwards and can't find anything missing.  Has anyone else had this problem?  Or have a different solution?

PS.  I know it is poor form, but I'm adding my code at the bottom for you to look at as well.

```
\documentclass[mathserif]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\LARGE{The Counterexample}
\small
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Start with two functions, $f_1$, $g_1$, and a set $S_1$. 
  \item Manipulate $f_1$, $g_1$, and add elements to $S_1$ to create $f_2, g_2$ and $S_2$
  \item Manipulate each $f_i, g_i$ and $S_i$ to create $f_{i+1}$, $g_{i+1}$, and $S_{i+1}$ as according to Boyce's Lemma 
  \item End up with two sequences of functions $\{f_i\}$ and $\{g_i\}$ uniformly converging to $f$ and $g$, respectively such that $f$ and $g$ commute under functional composition
\end{enumerate}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Besides some other problems with your code, the error is produced by a missing closing brace in `\item Manipulate each $f_i, g_i$ and $S_i$ to create $f_{i+1}$, $g_{i+1$, and $S_{i+1}$ as according to Boyce's Lemma` ; you missed the closing brace in `$g_{i+1$` which should be `$g_{i+1}$`

Comment: Surely you can boil it down to _one_ frame exhibiting the problem, possibly eliminating pstricks in the process, too?

Comment: You aren't using the size commands correctly, they don't have an argument, they are switches.

Comment: THANK YOU ALL SO MUCH!!!  The brace was the thing messing it up. But I will fix the size command stuff as well.

Comment: Don't use `\large{...}`; instead use `{\large ...}`. This goes for *all* font *switches* as they are declaration and don't take an argument. `\textbf{..}` (and friends) are different.

Comment: I took the liberty of making your example more minimal. In the future, see how to create a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because solved in comments